# How do I set up a port forwarding through SSH?

Tags: ssh, vpn, proxy, tunneling

I have a shell account (Debian) and I want all my localhost browser internet traffic to go through that shell account.

I know how to configure the internet browser and how to configure Putty for port forwarding, what I do not know is what I need to do on the server for this to happen.

Anyone knows what I should do on the server so that it will accept port forwarding? It does not seem to work with the default configuration.

Comment: Are you using something like: ssh -l username -L localport:server:port sshserver?

Comment: That is local port forwarding it will not allow the OP to tunnel all internet traffic, just the specified server will be browseable thru the tunnel created this way. The OP is probably looking for a SOCKS proxy which is perfectly doable with SSH

Answer (score 8):

Inside the `sshd_config` file just change the `#PermitTunnel` setting from `no` to `yes`.

from

```
#PermitTunnel no
```

to

```
PermitTunnel yes
```

Comment: ...and recycle sshd.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247790/121504

Answer (score 5):

> I want all my localhost browser
>   internet traffic to go through that
>   shell account.

```
ssh -D 8080 -T -f -l username proxy_host
```

- Will create a dynamic port forwarding (SOCKS proxy).
- `-T` will not allocate a tty
- `-f` will make SSH to go immediately into background

  - For this to work you need to use public key authentication
  - at least on debian have a look at ssh-copy-id
- Now you just need to configure your browser to go thru the specified port

Leave out `-T`and `-f` while testing the setup. The local port forwarding (`-L [listenaddress]:localport:remotehost:remoteport ssh_host`) will only work for the remotehost (e.g. `ssh -L 8080:google.com:80 ssh_host` will only forward traffic to `google.com` over the `ssh_host` not all web traffic)

If that doesn't work please update your question with the output of the SSH command with the `-vvv` switch added.

Answer (score 2):

When using `ssh -R 8080:google.com:80 ssh_host`

on `sshd_config`

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

should be to listen on wildcard or external interface not just loopback.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend this:
http://blog.slowb.ro/2013/06/21/create-a-ssh-based-vpn-system/

To summarise, parse `-D [port]` on to your ssh command, when making a connection. But the port must be on or above port 1025+.